# Big o notation -- while loops

Tags: big-o

what would the big o notation be for this program?

```
x = int(input("Enter a stride:"))
start = [0, 1]
end = int(input("Enter an endpoint:")) 

def xbonacci(signature, n, x): # returns all numbers in xbonacci under n
    seq = list(signature[:n])
    while sum(seq[-x:]) <= n:
        seq.append(sum(seq[-x:]))
    return seq

print(xbonacci(start, end, x))
```

I understand runtime for iterating through a list but in this application there will never be a set number of iterations. it always returns the sequence up to a given number but the length of the sequence changes based on x.

Comment: What is `m` in the function?

Comment: oops, m is x (aka the number of digits to be summed to produce the next digit). I fixed it